# HTML: Display indicators/images at specific coordinates on a web page

Tags: html, image, background, web, coordinates

I'll preface by saying that I'm new at web development.  I'm looking to display an image at specific coordinates on a page.  For example, if the page background is a world map, and I want specific cities to flash an indicator, what would be the easiest way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS styles to achieve what you want: http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp

I'll describe just a way to achieve that: use [Position](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp): absolute and top/bottom left/right properties to place the images at specific positions.

Thinking a little bit more... there's also the [HTML `<map>` Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp). See if it fits the bill. :)

Sample code:

```
<img src="WorldMap.jpeg" width="800" height="600" alt="Earth Planet"
     usemap="#planetmap" />

<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="sun.htm" alt="Sun" />
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="mercur.htm" alt="Mercury" />
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" href="venus.htm" alt="Venus" />
</map>
```